# How to convert this PHP timeDiff code to Android code?

Tags: php, android, time

I have this timeDiff function in PHP:

PHP Code:

```
function timeDiff( $firstTime,$lastTime ){
    // convert to unix timestamps
    $firstTime=strtotime($firstTime);
    $lastTime=strtotime($lastTime);

    // perform subtraction to get the difference (in seconds) between times
    $timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;

    // return the difference
    return $timeDiff;
}
```

now I want to use the above functionality in android, so I coded like this:

Android Code:

```
private double timeDiff(String startTime, String endTime ){
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date startTime_d = (Date) parser.parse(formater.format(startTime));
        Date endTime_d = (Date) parser.parse(formater.format(startTime));

        double dateDiff = startTime_d.getTime() - endTime_d.getTime();
        return dateDiff;

    }catch(ParseException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch( NullPointerException e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString() );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But logcat says java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

I'm a beginner android programmer thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

With the `getTime()` method of [Date objects](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) you can get the milliseconds till January 1st, 1970. If you want the difference between to dates you can calculate the difference in milliseconds as follows:

```
long diffMil = endTime_d.getTime() - startTime_d.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You called the parse method of the parser object with the output of the parser of the formater object. I believe this is incorrect. Try this:

```
private double timeDiff(String startTime, String endTime ){
try {

    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date startTime_d = (Date) parser.parse(startTime);
    Date endTime_d = (Date) parser.parse(endTime);

    double dateDiff = startTime_d.getTime() - endTime_d.getTime();
    return dateDiff;

}catch(ParseException e){
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch( NullPointerException e){
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString() );
}

return 0;

}
```